# Launching a binary from inside js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a way to launch a binary without loading it into a file and launching that way. I want to download it to a variable in memory and launch it that way. The binary is a packaged node js script that runs a server. Im working in javascript.

**the basic run down is**

get binary from the main server

- Done by downloading it from the server

run binary inside memory

del binary after the application closes

Comment: What does "run binary inside memory" mean?

Comment: I mean not downloading it to a file and executing it that way. When you download from a server with js. you can store the result in memory.

Comment: I don't think there's a trivial way to do that, but could be wrong. Seems unlikely because of the massive security risk.